# Spring @Transactional . Save entity in main thread and select in new thread in one transaction

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I have method in my service:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ImportChargesHandler implements SendRequestHandler {
...

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public void process(SendRequestRequest request, String fullRequest) {

    String guid = sendRequestService.saveImportChargesRequest(...);

    taskExecutor.execute(() -> importChargesOperation.importChargesRequest(request, guid));

  }
}
```

in this method I have 2 logik parts:

1. `saveImportChargesRequest` - create some object, save in DB and return `id(guid)`
2. `importChargesRequest` - call in new Thread. I pass saved `id(guid)` and use into this method(make select by guid)

But when I save object in DB in first method and pass id to second method, when I make select by id into second method I get exception(entity not found) or success result. I think this happens because when I make select - save method from previos method not persist data and I do not know about this data.

I tried `saveAndFlush()` when save object to DB - when I mae select data alreade flushed and I can select it. But sometimes I can not select does not matter.

```
-> start main method with @Transactional
------transaction begin------------
   -> start fist internal method for save entity
      -> save entity
      -> flush
      -> return id
  -----start new thread------------
   -> start second method
   -> select entity by id(id from first method)
   -> exception(not found) or success select(it depends)
------transaction commit-----------
```

Now I removed `@Transactional` from main method. And first and second method has `@Transactional`. I have this logik

```
-> start main method without @Transactional
    ------transaction begin------------
       -> start fist internal method for save entity
          -> save entity
          -> flush
          -> return id
      ------transaction commit-----------
      -----start new thread------------
      ------transaction begin------------
       -> start second method
       -> select entity by id(id from first method)
       -> success select
    ------transaction commit-----------
```

But I do not know correct this implemetation or not. And how can I fix first implementation - save data in main thread and select in new thread in One transaction?

Comment: AFAIK you can't do it in one transaction with spring because of the new thread. You can do it with manual transaction management, but this can be quite difficult to manage

Comment: Why are you saving the entity and then re-retrieving it? Why are you doing it in two different threads?

Comment: @Kayaman I need saved entity in main thread. If I pass entity in parameter I will have some problems - when I try get lazy method from this entity. I pass only id and select it in new thread. in main thread I save request data, and start new thread for heavy processing. In new Thread I select data and make process for this

Comment: Why don't you use the same thread? If you intend to do heavy processing, leave that out of the transaction. You can finish the transaction first, then process the data on the background. That would make some sense, your current approach is wrong in so many ways.

Comment: I save request in main thread to DB(it is fast), start mew thread for processing and return Responcse for user - ACCEPTED.  After that in new thread Iprocess request on the background. I wrote in my question that now I use different transactions, and I wanted to know whether I was doing the right thing.

Comment: You might be doing the right thing (although maybe not in the best way) if you don't need those operations to span a single transaction.

Comment: @ip696 So you want to make one transaction which can make rollback of all data and in the same time give response to the user that his/her data is accepted before you are sure that the data will be saved? I think in almost all situations this is wrong. You must double check what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

Why you need a second thread? Please try to remove the second thread and use only one. If you still need second thread then you need to commit the first transaction before get the result as you already did. You must also know that with your second approach you will have problem to rollback the transactions if you need to clear all preserved data. That why it is good if you consider to make it in one thread.